# I am using Replit to code but every time I try to import anything this error happen: imported but unused

Tags: python

[This is what appears for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Eyho.png)

I can't even import the random module I don't know why it does this,  is this problem only face me or everyone who  use replit

Comment: Have you _read_ the warning?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. This is a [warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)

> Warning messages are typically issued in situations where it is useful
> to alert the user of some condition in a program, where that condition
> (normally) doesn’t warrant raising an exception and terminating the
> program. For example, one might want to issue a warning when a program
> uses an obsolete module.

You can ignore warnings. This warning is saying that you do not use the imported module/library